# assign a regular expression as the value of a key with yq

Tags: regex, bash, yq

Specifically using https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

I would like to do an operation like this on a LinkML file, as part of a GNU Makefile, where the shell is bash

```bash
yq -i '(.classes.[].slot_usage.[] | select(.multivalued == true and .string_serialization="{text};{float} {unit}") | .pattern) = "^[^;\t\n\r]+;[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-
9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)? [^;\t\n\r]+$$"' file.yaml
```

Ie, I want to allow some text, then a semicolon, then a floating point number, and then some more text. I don't want any whitespace except x20 to be allowed.

but I am getting

```yaml
        pattern: |-
          ^[^;\t
          \r]+;[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)? [^;\t
          \r]+$
```

I don't want the `\n` to be interpreted as a new line, and I would prefer if the `pattern` value didn't wrap

Comment: I don't know LinkML, but have you tried escaping the backslash itself, i.e. `\n` to `\\n`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. When escaping the backslash, the first backslash remains in the pattern and the remaining `\n` is interpreted as a new line.

Comment: I switched from `\n` to `\x0A` in my yq operation. I'm checking to see if the LinkML validator understands that as a new line now.

Comment: I had a similar discovery: When you replace `\n` with `\\"+"n` (breaking up `\n`, then concatenating again with `+`) it seems to work. (Also, [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) doesn't seem to have this issue, neither does [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq).)